# What is electric field on the surface of a surface charge?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

Electric field just near the surface of a surface charge is $\dfrac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} (\hat{n})$ on one side and $-\dfrac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_0} (\hat{n})$ on the other side.

What would be the electric field on the surface of a surface charge?

Comment: How are you getting two different signs? If the surface is positively charged the field will be + on both sides (pointing away from the surface). If it is negatively charged, the field will be - on both sides (pointing into the surface).

Comment: w.r.t. our coordinate system, the unit vector has been inverted in the latter.

Comment: Is the surface positively or negatively charged?

Comment: well...if you consider the electric field the direction a test charge would move to... and you are in the plane of symmetry...

Comment: well, there is no *on* the surface. You are *above* or *in* the surface. Where would a test charge move to if it is *in* the surface?

Comment: @mikuszefski: (1) "there is no *on* the surface". Do  you mean there is no electric field ($\mathbf{E}=0$) on the surface? If yes, why is it so? Can you explain in an answer? (2) What is the difference between "on the surface" and "in the surface"?

Comment: 1) Symmetry 2) No, as the phrase *on the surface* does not make sense. What do you mean by *on the surface*. Which distance would that be?